# Rails Undefined Method for Has_Many/Belongs_To Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where an admin has to create a custom price per user before they buy a product.  A `pricing` `belongs_to` a `user` and a `product`, a `user` `has_many` `pricings`, and a `product` `has_many` `pricings`.  The routes are like this:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users, only: [:show]
  resources :products do
    resources :pricings
  end
```

On the `users#show` page, I am trying to get a list of the `pricings` for that user.  I have the following in my `users_controller`:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @products_with_pricing = Product.joins(:pricings).group("products.id").having("count(products.id) > ?",0)
end
```

And this on my `users#show` view:

```
<% @products_with_pricing.each do |product| %>
    <% if product.pricing.user == current_user %>
        <%= product.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This shows all the product names for all the `pricings` if I omit the `if ....== current_user` statement, but with that statement I am getting a `NoMethod` error on the if statement line that says:

> undefined method 'pricing' for # Did you
>   mean? pricings`

Can anyone set me straight as to the best way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: can you paste more detailed log? line number etc.

Answer (score 2):

product **has_many** pricings

That means that to get a product's pricings, you need to call `product.pricings`, which will return a collection of pricings. The error youre seeing is correct, product does not have a `pricing` method that returns one pricing object, it has a `pricings` method that returns many pricings.

If your goal is to only fetch products whose pricings also belong to the user, i'd recommend adjusting your SQL query to accomplish this

```
Product.joins(pricings: :users)
.where(pricings: { user: { id: current_user.id } })
.group("products.id")
.having("count(products.id) > ?",0)
```

note: you may need to mess with the plurality of pricings and users in the where and joins

This query is introducing a new joins and a where clause that will filter products whose pricings have a user with an id of the current user, so you wont need to have the if statement at all

Comment: This is helpful as I am not familiar with joins statements. I tried this and troubleshot it to `@products_with_pricing = Product.joins(pricings: :user).where(pricings: { user: { id: current_user.id } }).group("products.id").having("count(products.id) > ?",0)` but I'm still getting a lengthy error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: product.id: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "pricings" ON "pricings"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "pricings"."user_id" WHERE "pricings"."user_id" = NULL GROUP BY product.id HAVING count(products.id) > 0`

Comment: are you sure you wrote `.group("products.id")` and not `.group("product.id")` (singular). also, it looks like you dont have a `current_user` signed in, because its looking for user_id = NULL

Comment: Absolutely positive on both fronts.  `.group("products.id")` and I know there is a current user because it's on the `users#show` page that is accessed via a link with `current_user` in the path.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the fact that a `pricing` `belongs_to` a `user`.  Do I need to somehow indicate this in my routes?  A model can `belong_to` two different things, right?